# How can I include a download link to an arbitrary file in a Github Pages page?

Tags: github, github-pages

It my GitHub Pages page for my project, the only download options are for the `.zip` and the `.tar.gz` files (the standard ones including "See this on GitHub"). I want to have a link to download another file (a `.exe` file) without having to put it in my GitHub repository. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the `.exe` file? Is it a compiled version of your code?

Comment: @Chris Yes, but it shouldn't matter what the file is... It could be a `.txt` or a `.docx` even.

Comment: Related to a specific revision of your source code though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how GitHub Pages relates here (this likely depends on the theme you're using), but one good option for sharing pre-built versions of your software is to [create a GitHub Release](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-releases). This will prompt you to create a tag for the version of your source code you wish to release and let you upload additional files:

> Optionally, to include binary files such as compiled programs in your release, drag and drop or select files manually in the binaries box.

This file won't be added to your Git repository. It's attached to the GitHub-specific Release, and it can then be downloaded from your repository's releases tab, just like source archives.